# MySQL Workbench: How to keep the connection alive

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, connection-timeout

**Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query**

I am using MySQL Workbench. Also, I am running a batch of inserts, about 1000 lines total (Ex. `INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mysource1; INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mysource2;...mysource3...mysource4` multiplied 1000 times) Each batch takes a considerable amount of time, some of them, more than 600 seconds.

**How can I configure workbench, to continue working overnight, without stopping and without losing the connection?**

Answer (score 498, accepted):

From the now [unavailable](https://web.archive.org/web/20130322031356/http://www.hassmann-software.de/mysql-workbench-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-after-600-seconds) internet archive:

> Go to Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor and set to a higher value this parameter: DBMS connection read time out (in seconds). For instance: 86400.
>
> Close and reopen MySQL Workbench. Kill your previously query that
>   probably is running and run the query again.

Comment: There is a bug in all version of MySQL Workbench beyond 6.0.x on Mac OS : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37890150/1014813

Comment: This worked for me, but had to restart the editor to take effect.

Comment: @lepix Is this bug fixed?

Comment: A restart of the editor is needed for this to take effect after changing the values.

Comment: You can set it to 0 to just skip read timeout

Comment: No need to restart mysql workbench in recent versions.
At least version 8.0.26 don't require a restart, I assume the same is true for alot of earlier version.

Comment: This helped me too. Suddenly one bigger query would time out when running in MySQL Workbench. Turns out it just crept over 30 seconds. I did have to restart though, for it to take effect. Thanks for taking the time, over 10 years ago ;)

Answer (score 50):

If you are using a "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" type of connection, under "Preferences"->"Others" there is "SSH KeepAlive" field. It took me quite a while to find it :(

Comment: Why are you repeating an answer?

Comment: @JanDoggen I don't see any other answer that points where in MySQL Workbench you can change "SSH KeepAlive" which by default is 0 => disabled. I only see an answer that suggest to change server's ssh settings...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, as the setting here overrides the client config files ~/.ssh/config and /etc/ssh/ssh_config This is an absolute must for mobile broadband.

Comment: Could you please add an example of value to use in your answer? Do your recommend something like `1800` seconds?

Comment: @A.L it depends on your context. In my case, the SSH connection was expiring in 3 minutes (180 seconds) so I set my SSH KeepAlive to 30 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, for me I don't see "DBMS connection read time out" in Mysql workbench 6.3

Answer (score 26):

I had a similar problem where `CREATE FULLTEXT` timed out after 30 seconds:

[image: error]

Setting DBMS connection read timeout interval to 0 under Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor fixed the issue for me:

[image: fix error]

Also, I did not have to restart mysql workbench for this to work.

Answer (score 19):

In 5.2.47 (at least on Mac), the location of the related preferences is:

> MySQL Workbench > Preferences > SQL Editor

Then you'll see both:

> `DBMS connection keep-alive interval (in seconds):`
> `DBMS connection read time out (in seconds):`

The latter is where you'll want to up the limit from `600` to something a bit more.

Comment: I have setted my DBMS connection read timeout to 86400 second, after around 7200 seconds of running some query I still get error 2013. Does anyone know anything about it?

Comment: you need to restart Workbench after changes

Answer (score 12):

In my case after trying to set the SSH timeout on the command line and in the local server settings. @Ljubitel solution solved the issue form me.

One point to note is that in Workbench 6.2 the setting is now under advanced

[image]

Comment: In 6.3 Advanced has been renamed as Others.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a "Standard TCP/IP over SSH" type of connection, it might be the ssh server that keeps timing out, in which case, you would have to edit TCPKeepAlive related settings in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on your server.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error 2013 and none of the above preference changes did anything to fix the problem.  I restarted mysql service and the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

OK - so this issue has been driving me crazy - v 6.3.6 on Ubuntu Linux. None of the above solutions worked for me. Connecting to localhost mysql server previously always worked fine. Connecting to remote server always timed out - after about 60 seconds, sometimes after less time, sometimes more.

What finally worked for me was upgrading Workbench to 6.3.9 - no more dropped connections.

Answer (score 1):

in mysql-workbech 5.7 edit->preference-> SSH -> SSH Connect timeout (for SSH DB connection)
[image]