# How to keep connection without lost in mysql from server side?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL DB configuration , The symptom for both a windows DB client tool and an application client is that after a while the connection is lost and client would need to reestablish the connection. It seems that there’s a setting on the MySQL DB that the connections are timing out after some time.

how to keep connection without lost in mysql from server side.

is there any way to set server side  to keep connection alive.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712512/mysql-workbench-how-to-keep-the-connection-alive

Comment: so it is client side.if i am connecting from apps ,we have any option to set in server side.

Comment: use perstistent connections

Comment: depends on your tool.. either set the timeout or use a persistent connection. how do we know what tool you are using?

Comment: i am not talking about tool ,if i use aplication how to stay long time with out time out.