# MySQL Workbench kicks me off before query runs

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL workbench to run a query. The query is reasonably big. When I limit the results to say 50 records the results are as expected. But when I remove the limit, the query runs for ~ 5 minutes then prompts me to re-enter my password. After doing so I see the query has not run and has stopped working.

It seems like there is a setting that kicks me off after a certain amount of time but I cannot see it in the drop down menus.

Has anyone experienced this? Any advice?

** Update**
Query ran and Workbench says results returned but they are not and I got the screen shot error pop up here:

[image]

Comment: What version of Workbench? OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like one of three things are the likely culprit.

1. MySql Workbench may be timing out.

   - *[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15712616/1551) may help with #1*

     > Go to Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor and set to a higher value this
     >   parameter: DBMS connection read time out (in seconds). For instance:
     >   86400.
     >
     > Close and reopen MySQL Workbench. Kill your previously query that
     >   probably is running and run the query again.
2. The mySQL server is timing out

   - *You will need access to the server's timeout configuration*
3. Something network related (but far less likely if your timeout happens consistently at around 5 mins)

   - *There are a number of factors that might need adjusting.*
   - If #2, you will need access to the server's timeout configuration
   - If #3, well, there are a number of factors that might need adjusting.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. That setting is currently at 10000 seconds which is 166 minutes. Surely then this cannot be the issue since I'm kicked off after around 5 mins? Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: If that's the case then I'd guess you have a timeout on the server.  Do you have access to the box or access to a DBA with access to the box?

Comment: I will check with our chief dev (We're a small co). But I wonder because other people in the company use MySQL Workbench on the same databases and don;t experience this. Just me. And, not to potentially divert attention from the cause but just incase, I'm on windows and those who don;t have this issue are on Macs. I wonder if that's coincidence or actually a signal of where to check?

Comment: Thanks again for the info, I'll update here when I ask our dev to look into our servers timeout

Comment: I don't know of anything platform related unless your machine has a system-wide setting for db timeouts, and I don't think that's likely.  Can you run your same query on another machine to see if it is the query itself perhaps?

Comment: Also, the query itself runs in 0.797 seconds. All the time is in "Fetching". Is that expected?

Comment: How large is the data set?  You could potentially have a huge data set for a query that runs rather quickly.