# Create index causes 'Lost connection to MySQL'

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table which is defined like [this](http://prntscr.com/6a0zcs). Where `ProviderId` is the primary key, and `StateID` is the foreign key, that comes from another table. It is running in my laptop, therefore, it is a local database. In my table I have around 9 million entries. I ran the following command to create a new index for the table:

```
CREATE INDEX name_addr ON providers (ProviderName, Address, StateID, Zip);
```

It ran around 10 minutes, and I got this error message:

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query - 600.547 sec
```

I checked my log, and the result was this:

```
150226 13:07:31    12 Query CREATE INDEX name_addr ON providers (ProviderName, Address, StateID, Zip)
150226 13:17:32    13 Connect   root@localhost on 
           13 Query set autocommit=1
           13 Query SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
           13 Query SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE 'lower_case_table_names'
           13 Query SELECT current_user()
           13 Query SET CHARACTER SET utf8
           13 Query SET NAMES utf8
           13 Query SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1
           13 Query SELECT CONNECTION_ID()
           13 Query SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'
           13 Query USE `workflydb`
           13 Query set autocommit=1
```

Although, I got an error message, when I checked my indexes, the result was [this](http://prntscr.com/6a10nv). I don't know what the problem can be, and how to solve it, or whether my created index actually works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

look for a property like 'connection keep alive' in your MySql Workbench. See this answer: [MySQL Workbench: How to keep the connection alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712512/mysql-workbench-how-to-keep-the-connection-alive)

Answer (score 0):

This may because of timeout problem. Change time out to a larger value. You can do it in command line interface or in mysql workbench.