# MySQL Workbench 6.3 not returning results with more than 2000 rows

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am running MySQL Workbench 6.3 on a Windows 7 machine 64-bit laptop. When a do a simple query to get all the data in a single table with ~400 rows of data, the query stays in "running . . . " status and eventually returns the Error Code: 2013 Lost Connection to MySQL server at "waiting for initial communication". If I limit the results to 1000 rows, the query works fine, its only when I allow for more than 2000 rows does this occur.

I do have "Use compression protocol" enabled, which I had hoped would fix the issue.

The other thing I noticed, that if I run the query on my Mac I do not have this issue, I get more than 10,000 rows with no issues.

Has anyone else had this issue and resolved it?

~michemali

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a time out issue. Please refer to this post to see if this resolves your issue:

[MySQL Workbench: How to keep the connection alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712512/mysql-workbench-how-to-keep-the-connection-alive)