# MySQL Workbench - My Server has gone away

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, connection-timeout

I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.3.6 (64-bit) to enter DB queries, however after a short period of inactivity - I don't know exactly how long but it can't be more than 3-4 minutes (e.g. whilst I'm typing this question), the server seems to disconnect.

This isn't an issue with the server, because when I'm using Eclipse data tools, or a SSH terminal, this doesn't occur - however, the solutoin given on the question: [MySQL Workbench drops connection when idle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811517/mysql-workbench-drops-connection-when-idle) hasn't solved the issue - no matter how "low" I set the DBMS "keep-alive" interval it still loses its connection.

This may be a duplicate (but I couldn't find one that seems to really fit these circumstances)

Thanks,

David

EDIT: Have tried recommended answer below - but unfortunately despite setting it for 600s, it timed out by 4 minutes

[MySQL Workbench: How to keep the connection alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712512/mysql-workbench-how-to-keep-the-connection-alive)

To clarify, I've included a screenshot of my SQL editor settings where I have dropped the time between keep-alive packets, and increased the time-out times - just in case I have done this incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712512/mysql-workbench-how-to-keep-the-connection-alive)?  Your workbench session with the underlying database is timing out, which is different than the database itself shutting down.  This is why you don't have a problem with your code (which maintains the appropriate session).

Comment: Will try out now, and demark this question as a duplicate if it works

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt have any effect - see update

Comment: Please also let us know which exact version of Workbench you are using.

Comment: Have edited, is workbench 6.3 64-bit

Comment: If you set the keep alive interval to 1 second, do you still lose the connection after 4 minutes?